# sqlite issue in iOS accessing two table at same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, sqlite

I hope all doing well, I have one query regarding the sqlite .
Is that possible that  two different sqlite table access at ones .
ex.
I have table A ans B .Can access A and B at same time .insert updating table value .

I have two different table,Table1 and table2 in myDatabase( test_db.sqlite).

Table 1 is only access by main thread.
 Table 2 will be only access by background thread.

Now let c.
I have open the database connection using background thread…for inserting the value into table2.
 while inserting the value into table2………….my main thread tries to open the same database connection at the same time to retrieve the data from table 1……and the app crash.

how to open the same database connection concurrently.

please check this edit one

Comment: You should know about joins and bridge table

Comment: Can you maybe distill this into a single question? What errors are you getting when tou try to do multiple inserts at the same time? What code are you using to do so?

Comment: Generally we make one global database instance for handling database operations.You can fire database query for you two tables separately in a way that second is performed when first is successful.So it can avoid any ambiguity if exist. For more share your code with us.

Comment: You can use performSelectorOnMainThread method with waitUntillDone set for YES.

Comment: when  i am trying to access database get lock

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]

You are getting problems by accessing the Database in different threads. You can deal with this problem by using thread safe mode.

From [SQL docs](http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html):

> SQLite support three different threading modes:
>
> Single-thread. In this mode, all mutexes are disabled and SQLite is unsafe to use in more than a single thread at once.
>
> Multi-thread. In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads provided that no single database connection is used simultaneously in two or more threads.
>
> Serialized. In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads with no restriction.

So, you can use the `SQLITE_THREADSAFE` compile-time parameter to select the threading mode.

I suggest that you open a different DB connection in each thread, or rebuild SQLite in serialised mode (with SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1).

---

OLD Answer:

It's difficult to answer your problem if you do not provide the exact error you are receiving. But, making the assumption that your queries are ok, the most probable cause is that you are not handling your sqlite flow correctly.

I suppose that your problem is that you are updating table "A" and then when trying to update table "B" it crashes. That's why you are trying to create a single query to update both of them.

So, before reusing your `sqlite3_stmt` to make the second query, you should, first, call   `sqlite3_finalize(yourStatement)` to release the statement from memory, and then, if you want to make the second query just call `sqlite3_prepare_v2` again, so the database is ready to accept the next query after that.